# Convert dates to %y-%m-%d format in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime-format

I have a csv file with column 'date' which has dates in many different formats like ddmmyy, mmddyy,yymmdd. I want to convert all the dates to y-m-d format

```
df=pd.read_csv(file)
df=df['date] .dt.strftime(%y-%m-%d)
```

This code gives error: "Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values"

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 0:-**

Your `dataframe`:-

```
df=pd.read_csv('your file name.csv')
```

**Step 1:-**

firstly convert your **'date' column** into `datetime` by using `to_datetime()` method:-

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

**Step 2:-**

And If you want to convert them in `string` like format Then use:-

```
df['date']=df['date'].astype(str)
```

Now if you print df or write df(if you are using jupyter notebook)

```
Output:-

0    2020-01-01
1    2020-12-31
2    2020-06-20
```

Comment: Thanks. How to sort by date in this case?

Comment: Just use `df.sort_values(by='date',ascending=True)` and if you want to `sort` in descending order then set `ascending=False` in `sort_values()` method.............btw if this answer helped you then try considering accept this answer

Comment: The output gives 20-01-01. Instead, I want 2020-01-01. It seems dt.strftime(%y-%m-%d) trimes the year part. Is there a way to gives output as 2020-01-01?

Comment: Yeah just use `df['date']=df['date'].astype(str)` it will convert your **'date'** column into `Object` type and you will get `2020-01-01` as output

Comment: Sorry, where to insert this? I tried inserting it before pd.to_datetime so that it convert date to a string and also at the end. but it gives error: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: Use `df['date']=df['date'].astype(str)` after `pd.to_datetime`...i.e firstly use `df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` then `df['date']=df['date'].astype(str)`

Comment: It's throwing up same error. I converted to dataframe as below: df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date']) then  df['date']=pd.DataFrame(df['date']), then
      df['date']=df['date'].astype(str). Again this shows output as 20-01-01 only and not as 2020-01-01.

Comment: Bruh....You are doing wrong steps...I edited my answer Just have a look and follow along with steps

Answer (score 5):

You can utilise [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) -

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['1/2/2020','12/31/2020','20-Jun-20'],columns=['Date'])
>>> df
         Date
0    1/2/2020
1  12/31/2020
2   20-Jun-20
>>> 
>>> df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
>>> df
        Date
0 2020-01-02
1 2020-12-31
2 2020-06-20
>>> 
>>> df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%y-%m-%d')
>>> 
>>> df
       Date
0  20-01-02
1  20-12-31
2  20-06-20
>>>
```